# Does AT&T U-Verse phone service cause problems with modems?

Tags: router, modem, voip, dial-up

I have landline phone service with ATT Uverse. My router is a 2wire, and when I go to the router homepage, I see something that says the VoIp service is either idle or active. I also have a modem in my computer, connected to the ATT phone service. Whenever I try to use the modem to connect to the internet or to send a fax, it doesn't work. At first, I thought the issue was the dial tone. When the phone is first picked up, it beeps before the dial tone. So I tried keeping the phone line open until I got a dial tone, and then tried to connect to the internet. It started to connect, but when it finally did connect, the connection wouldn't transfer any data. I think the problem is that the VoIp prevents the modem from sending and receiving the right frequencies, but I am not sure. I want to know if it is a problem with the VoIp, and if so, how can I fix it? Or, is it a problem with my modem setup?

Answer (score 0):

Your U-Verse service is VoIP and it is meant to carry voice and it will compress your voice vigorously. Your modem, on the other hand, is expecting it has a high quality analog carrier to carry its digital signal.

Try to reduce the speed of your modem. I would start with 2400bps. As Fax service should still work with U-Verse and it starts at 9600kbps.

Some more reference for you:
https://forums.att.com/t5/Features-and-How-To/Faxing-with-ATT-uverse-voip/td-p/2820619

The part that puzzles me is you say "it beeps before the dial tone". I suppose your modem is trying to dial. This is unusual as it is supposed to wait for a dial-tone before dialing. I would make sure your modem is setup properly. You may want to reset the modem or dial script to factory default.

Comment: The beeping is not caused by the modem. It happens when I take the phone off the hook. The phone plays a tone 10 times for about 2 seconds before the dial tone, even when the modem isn't connected to the phone line.